# In what episode(s) do the lines "Doctor Who?" "If you like" occur?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

I was curious if someone could help me remember which Doctor had this exchange in the new series... I can't remember the Doctor (though I think it was the 11th) or episode.

> THE DOCTOR: I'm the Doctor!
>
> [UNKNOWN]: Doctor Who?
>
> THE DOCTOR: If ya like!

It was very snappy comedic timing. I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only example off the top of my head is the Season 7 episode ["Hide"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide_(Doctor_Who)), when Clara and the Doctor enter the "haunted" house we get this exchange:

> **The Doctor:** Hello, I'm the Doctor.
>
> **Professor Palmer:** Doctor what?
>
> **The Doctor:** If you like. [Proceeds to do Doctor-y things]

And you're right, this is the Eleventh Doctor.

Answer (score 4):

That would be ["Hide" from series 7](https://www.planetclaire.org/quotes/doctorwho/series-seven/hide/), but the line is “Doctor what?”.